# Z3Py: constraint of not equal tuples

Tags: z3, z3py

I've got bunch of Bools:

```
a=Bool('a')
...
z=Bool('z')
```

How to pack some of these bools to tuples and then to add constraint about their non-equality?

I tried:

```
tuple1=(a,b,c,d)
tuple2=(e,f,g,h)
# so far so good
s=Solver()
s.add(tuple1 != tuple2)
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python tuple does not get reflected to Z3 tuples.
You can create a tuple type for Z3 in the following wayL

```
from z3 import *
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h = Ints('a b c d e f g h')

tuple = Datatype('tuple')
tuple.declare('tuple',('1', IntSort()), ('2', IntSort()), ('3', IntSort()), ('4', IntSort()))
tuple = tuple.create()
tuple1=tuple.tuple(a,b,c,d)
tuple2=tuple.tuple(e,f,g,h)
# so far so good
s=Solver()
s.add(tuple1 != tuple2)
print s.check()
print s.model()
```

In this case you get tuple disequality that Z3 understands. 
Z3 does not understand the != or == operator between python tuples.
Perhaps it is possible to extend the python support to such data-types
but the distribution does not support such extensions.

Comment: Just one question: can I replace tuples with arrays, size of which will be set during runtime? And then fill them and compare?